# Why is my custom Razor extension not generating attributes correctly?

Tags: razor, html-helper

I see a lot of questions dabbling around the edges of this one, but not quite the same. I wrote the simple HtmlHelper extension method below, to create anchor links that have fixed text of `<` and a `target="_back"` attribute, added to the usual routing and HTML parameters, but the result is not at all what I expected.

Instead of:

```
<a href="controller/action/id?etc" target="_back">&lt;</a>
```

I get:

```
<a Count="1" Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" href="controller/action/id?etc">&lt;</a>"
```

Here is my HtmlHelper extension method:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString BackLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controller = null, object routeValuesObject = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary rvd = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        rvd.Add("target", "_back");
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink("<", actionName, controller, routeValuesObject, rvd);
    }
```

I have used similar calls before and not seen this happen. What should I be converting the result of `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` to and why doesn't it do the job it was apparently designed for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again it is a case of the compiler being too smart for its own good :)

There are two similar overloads for `htmlHelper.ActionLink`:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, 
           object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, 
           RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
```

The problem I had was it deciding to use the first `object, object` variation as the route values were not converted like the HTML attributes were.

So the solution is to convert the route values to a `RouteValueDictionary` as well:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString BackLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controller = null, object routeValuesObject = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValuesObject);
        RouteValueDictionary htmlAttr = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        htmlAttr.Add("target", "_back");
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink("<", actionName, controller, routeValues, htmlAttr);
    }
```

This causes it to use the `RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes` method instead.